# Overflow: hidden but i still want to have the empty scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I set 'overflow:hidden' on my html body with Javascript when I press a button. But when I do that the whole body moves 5 pixels or so to the left because the space of the scrollbar is gone. How do i prevent that.

I can't set margin of the body to a specific size because the width of scrollbars differentiate between browsers

Comment: For the `li` elements,  try a css rule :  `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue? If so it would be helpful if you marked which answer was correct or if none of them helped you perhaps you could post an answer yourself? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the previous solution does not work anymore (see original answer below), I've come across another solution which works for me and, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth), it should work in all browser, with IE starting from version 6.
This solution to get the scrollbar width is even a bit simplified:

> 1. Append a div without a scrollbar to the body and position it off screen
> 2. Measure the client width of the div
> 3. Set the div to have a scrollbar (using css overflow style)
> 4. Measure the clientWidth of the div again
> 5. Remove the div
> 6. Return the difference of the two widths

And the code would look like this:

```
function scrollbarWidth() { 
    var div = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"></div>'); 
    // Append our div, do our calculation and then remove it 
    $('body').append(div); 
    var w1 = div.prop('clientWidth'); 
    div.css('overflow-y', 'scroll'); 
    var w2 = div.prop('clientWidth'); 
    $(div).remove();
    return (w1 - w2); 
}
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nv1cp1bs/2/) is a working jsFiddle.

---

#### Original answer (for completeness sake)

[Here](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/minute/calculate-scrollbar-width.php) is a solution to calculate the width of a scrollbar, which you can use in conjuction with some of the other answers here (and your own knowledge as far as I can tell).

The idea is to do the following steps:

> 1. Append two divs to the body and position them off screen
> 2. Measure the width of the inner div
> 3. Set the outer div to overflow
> 4. Measure the width of the inner div (again)
> 5. Remove the divs
> 6. Return the difference of the two widths

And here is the code, copied from the referenced page:

```
function scrollbarWidth() { 
    var div = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;"></div>'); 
    // Append our div, do our calculation and then remove it 
    $('body').append(div); 
    var w1 = $('div', div).innerWidth(); 
    div.css('overflow-y', 'scroll'); 
    var w2 = $('div', div).innerWidth(); 
    $(div).remove(); 
    return (w1 - w2); 
}
```

Comment: @Billy I can verify that, in the newer Chrome versions this does not work anymore. I didn't check in other browsers. I've found another solution, using .prop('clientWidth') demonstrated in this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nv1cp1bs/2/ and according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth it is supposed to work in all browsers, with IE from 6 and up, but I haven't personally tried it.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this old trick:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

What this does is force the scrollbar to always be visible.

Compare:

[normal JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

[JSFiddle with the vertical scrollbar always there](http://jsfiddle.net/Ftd8S/)

Comment: when i use that, then iam still able to scroll vertically when i push my button. I dont want to scroll, i only want to keep the space of the scrollbar

Comment: Hm, interesting. If you make a JSFiddle and post more code, I might be able to help further. Right now, it's difficult for me to know exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to add a disabled vertical scroll bar. If placed more prominent in CSS than the rest of the CSS, it should override whatever you've done to other portions.

```
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: when i use that, then iam still able to scroll vertically when i push my button. I dont want to scroll, i only want to keep the space of the scrollbar

Comment: Can you post the code you're presently using, or a link to any sourcecode/CSS? I'd suggest making a JSFiddle regardless - if this solution is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could always put a wrapper around the content that you are hiding and then place the overflow: scroll on div and overflow: hidden on the content div.

```
#wrapper { overflow-y: scroll; }
#content { overflow: hidden; }
```

See the attached fiddle for a working version

http://jsfiddle.net/15km/bfpAD/1/