# text of two tables with same width and <td> are not aligned in same line

Tags: html, css

I have two tables with same width and number of `<td>` in one row with same css for both tables but as you see in snippet first column of both tables are aligned properly but other columns are shifted left from heading 
Here i want a table with fixed headings at top and content part has scroll if content height is more than 100px.

```css
.headings,
.contents {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.headings td,
.contents td {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.content-subblock {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-subblock">
            <table class="headings">
                <tr>
                    <td>heading1</td>
                    <td>heading2</td>
                    <td>heading3</td>
                    <td>heading4</td>
                    <td>heading5</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="content-subblock">
            <table class="contents">
                <tr>
                    <td>link1</td>
                    <td>link2</td>
                    <td>link3</td>
                    <td>link4</td>
                    <td>link5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>link6</td>
                    <td>link7</td>
                    <td>link8</td>
                    <td>link9</td>
                    <td>link10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>link11</td>
                    <td>link12</td>
                    <td>link13</td>
                    <td>link14</td>
                    <td>link15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>link16</td>
                    <td>link17</td>
                    <td>link18</td>
                    <td>link19</td>
                    <td>link20</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think may be it's due to scroll on the right side of second table,Can anyone suggest me how can i align both `<td>` of heading and content table in one vertical column

Comment: please check my answer I updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use jQuery to make this happen please check that if this is what you
>   are looking for. you can try removing some data rows it will not show
>   scroller

---

***CODEPEN LINK***

[**[https://codepen.io/feizel/pen/QQZqpR?editors=1111][1]**](https://codepen.io/feizel/pen/QQZqpR?editors=1111)

```js
var contentHeight =  jQuery(".faizal--block").outerHeight();
var absoluteHeight = 100;
if(contentHeight > absoluteHeight){
  jQuery('.faizal--block').addClass('scrolling');
  jQuery('.headings').css('width', 'calc(100% - 15px)');
}else {
   jQuery('.headings').css('width', 'calc100%');
}
```

```css
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
    }
    .headings{
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .contents {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .headings td,
    .contents td {
        width: 20%;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .content-subblock {
        overflow: auto;
      background-color:white;
     
    }
    .scrolling{
      max-height:100px;
    }
    .scrolling_none{
      height:auto;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
    .headings td, .contents td{
      padding:0;
      background:red;
      border:none;
      color:#fff;
      text-indent:15px;
    }
    .headings td{
        background:#bc2d2d;
    }
    .contents td{
        background:grey;
    }
    .headings{
      background:red;
      font-weight:bold;
      background:#bc2d2d;
    }
    td{ 
      height:50px;
      border:3px solid #333 !important;
      font-size:16px;
      padding:0 !important;
      width:300px !important;
      line-height:50px;
        -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
        column-gap: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="content-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content-subblock">
                <table class="headings" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>heading1</td>
                        <td>heading2</td>
                        <td>heading3</td>
                        <td>heading4</td>
                        <td>heading5</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
  <div class="content-subblock faizal--block">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="contents">
                    <tr>
                        <td>link1</td>
                        <td>link2</td>
                        <td>link3</td>
                        <td>link4</td>
                        <td>link5</td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td>link1</td>
                        <td>link2</td>
                        <td>link3</td>
                        <td>link4</td>
                        <td>link5</td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td>link1</td>
                        <td>link2</td>
                        <td>link3</td>
                        <td>link4</td>
                        <td>link5</td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td>link1</td>
                        <td>link2</td>
                        <td>link3</td>
                        <td>link4</td>
                        <td>link5</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue, still content columns are shifted left from heading

Comment: @nidhi please check I updated, you should use cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" inside table

Comment: still it doesn't solution give some border to `td` and you can see the difference

Comment: @nidhi can you please put 1 screen shot of the border, i checked in console   no border showing for td, i attached the screen shots please check

Comment: yes border is not in your code but i suggest you that apply border and see what problem i am facing

Comment: @nidhi I hope this is what your are looking for  with border, have to minus the scroller with from full table with. width: calc(100% - 15px);

Comment: @nidhi added the styling in javascript, please check now when height is below 100px, width will be 100% and when height is quel or over 100px width will be (100% - 15px)

Comment: This is better solution but is it working for all browsers?

Comment: @nidhi i think it will work on all modern browsers because it is simple jQuery and css

Answer (score 1):

The width of the tables are not the same due to the overflow scrollbar on the bottom table.  You can add the following declaration to your content-subblock header div element to ensure the widths are consistent.  You may just want to add it to both to ensure a scroll bar is always present if this is dynamic content:

```
.content-subblock {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

However, it would be much better to just combine the tables.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</th>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Width of all cells is fixed  20% , as you can see i want scroll for content part only when content height is more than 100px for this reason i separated header and content part

Comment: I see what you mean, however the widths of the tables are not the same width, due to the scrollbar on your bottom table.  This will not be a consistent difference between browsers, I suppose if you really want to use this pattern, you can add `overflow-y: scroll` to your top table.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain how this can be accomplished.

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll` gives scroll at right of heading row which i don't want.

Comment: I want scroll only if content height  is more than 100px

Comment: There are more convoluted solutions, like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843087/overflow-hidden-but-i-still-want-to-have-the-empty-scrollbar - but it is probably a better idea to just change the design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Why You are using **heading** in separate table,this is not good practice.

### use below one.

```
 <style>
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
td{
border:1px solid;
}
.header{
  width:calc(100% - 17px);
  width:-webkit-calc(100% - 17px);
  width:-moz-calc(100% - 17px);
 height:25px; 
 background:#000;color:#fff;
}
</style>
<table class="header">
<tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">header</td>
  <td width="50%">header</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="container">
<table style="width:100%; ">
<tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
   <tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
   <tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
   <tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
   <tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
   <tr height="25">
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  <td width="50%">body</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I want fixed headings at top and content part has scroll if content's height is more than 100px